# ¿Existen las funciones en Java?

Tags: java, metodos

Estoy empezando con Java y me planteo la siguiente cuestión.

Dado que todo el código que se escribe en Java pertenece a una clase, las funciones que escribimos, ¿son siempre métodos?

Sé que un método es una función que pertenece a una clase y que una función es un bloque de código que está fuera de una clase.

Entonces, ¿esto quiere decir que nunca tenemos funciones en Java?

Comment: En realidad en java suele denominarse método aquel que se llama a partir de una instancia de un objeto, esto es, que necesitas hacer `MiClase x = new MiClase(); x.foo();` -> En este caso `foo()` sería un método. Por otro lado los métodos estáticos suelen considerarse funciones, puesto que no necesitas instanciar un objeto para llamarlos y suelen recibir los datos que necesitan como parámetro, por ejemplo `public static void changeName(MiClase x, String newName) { x.setName(newName);}` sería una función, aunque pueda estar definida dentro de `MiClase`.